# native stack error while restoring SharePoint 2013 site collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, restore

I have a SharePoint 2013 site collection backup and i am trying to restore this back up on another SharePoint 2013 site collection. Both SharePoint sites are on the same domain. But when i try to restore the site collection from backup, i am getting an error as -

```
Restore-SPSite : <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
At line:1 char:1
+ Restore-SPSite-Identity http://ksptestinst2:9999 -Path
"E:\SiteBackup\BackupSPS ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:
   SPCmdletRestoreSite) [Restore-SPSite], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreS
   ite
```

the command i use to restore site collection backup is -

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity http://ksptestinst2:9999 -Path "E:\SiteBackup\BackupSPSite.bak" -Force
```

i tried using

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity "http://ksptestinst2:9999/" -Path "E:\SiteBackup\BackupSPSite.bak" -Force -DatabaseServer KSQL2012SP\SQL
TESTDB -DatabaseName WSS_Content_KSPTESTINST2_9999
```

but both commands are giving same error.

Can anyone suggest how do we proceed?

Comment: My best bet is that there is a permission issue. What account are you using to restore the backup?

Comment: I am using a farm admin account to restore the backup. But the farm admin account for both servers are different.

Comment: So there is 2 different farms?

Comment: Yes 2 different farms in same domain

Comment: Try adding -Verbose flag and see if you get more information!

Answer (score 1):

Both Farm should have same Patch level, upgrade the existing source DB (upgrade-spcontentdatabase) then take a fresh backup (Backup-SPSite -Identity http://dev:4646/sites/st -Path “\dev\Backup\st.bak” -force), upgrade the existing destination DB, then do a restore (Restore-SPSite -Identity http://dev:4646 -Path “\dev\Backup\st.bak” -Confirm:$false -force)

It will work